# XPages: How to get selected rows from Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I Created a  responsive table with XPages datatable  and Using Plugin: [bootstrap-table-mobile](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/mobile) every thing work fine the view was able to toggle from table view on desktop to card view on mobile.

i then add a checkbox to the tavle in other to get some print onClick or onChange of the checbox but notting happen the event are not trigger. Is there Any work arround to it?
Below is my datatable

```
<xp:dataTable id="dataTable2" rows="30">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="table"></xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="data-show-columns" value="true">
            </xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="data-mobile-responsive" value="true"></xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="data-check-on-init" value="true"></xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="data-click-to-select" value="true">
            </xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="data-click-to-select" value="true"></xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:column id="column12">
            <xp:checkBox id="checkBox2">

                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewTable" id="eventHandler3">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
print("onClick_Server")}]]></xp:this.action>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[console.log("onClick_cllient")]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("onChange_Server")}]]></xp:this.action>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[console.log("onChange_client")]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:checkBox>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:column id="column14">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="id" value="#{curDoc.id}">

            </xp:text>
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:label value="Id" id="label10" for="column1" xp:key="header">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:column id="column13">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:label value="Item Mame" id="label2" for="column1"
                    xp:key="header">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="ItemName" value="#{curDoc.itemname}">

            </xp:text>
        </xp:column>
    </xp:dataTable>
```

Comment: May be this can help you, http://notesspeak.blogspot.nl/2013/09/creating-event-for-selected-row-in.html

Comment: thanks for the link, it work for me, why dont u add as an answer so i could accept it

Comment: I have added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help you to get a handle on the selected row, http://notesspeak.blogspot.nl/2013/09/creating-event-for-selected-row-in.html

Answer (score 1):

[Click this link to Run.. This may help you, if not means just ignore](https://jsfiddle.net/SubinVs/Lpczx1bv/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblemp">
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile No</th>
                    <th>Email Id</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="emp001" class="clickable-row">
                        <td>AAA</td>
                        <td>1111111</td>
                        <td>aaa@gmail.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="emp002" class="clickable-row">
                        <td>BBB</td>
                        <td>2222222</td>
                        <td>bbb@gmail.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="emp003" class="clickable-row">
                        <td>CCC</td>
                        <td>3333333</td>
                        <td>ccc@gmail.com</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<script>
    var emp_id = "";
    $('#tblemp').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        emp_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        alert(emp_id);
    });
</script>
```